# Object changes after subscribing to observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

From an `x.component.ts` I call `getSomething()` in `y.service.ts`. I subscribe to `getSomething()` because is returns an observable. The thing is that before the `.subscribe()` I have an object that has 4 elements inside, one of which is an array of number arrays (number[][]), and **after** the `.subscribe` that same array is now empty.

x.component.ts

```
this.y
      .getSomething()
      .pipe(
        //make an observable to pass to child component 
        tap(data => (this.pautaFinal$ = of(data))),
        // This object is just for development purpose
        tap(data => (this.pautaFinal = data)),
        // This is to change the number[][] object into a number[][][]
        // I need it that way
        tap(
          data =>
            (this.escalaPorcionada = this.transformEscala(
              data.escala.escalaArr,
              10
            ))
        )
      )
      .subscribe();

// Makes an array of number arrays, into an array of arrays of chunkSize number arrays.
transformEscala(escala: number[][] = [], chunkSize: number): number[][][] {
    let results: number[][][] = [];
    while (escala.length) {
      results.push(escala.splice(0, chunkSize));
    }
    return results;
  }
```

In this x.component I've also tried, instead of the third `tap`, a `map(data => data.escala.escala)` and then `.subscribe(data => this.escalaPorcionada = this.transformEscala(data, 10).

```
y.service.ts
  getSomething(): Observable<Pauta> {
    let admin: DatosAdmin;
    let escala: Escala;
    let rubrica: Rubrica;
    let criterios: Criterios;
    this.datosAdminAcumul$.subscribe(datos => (admin = datos));
    this.escalaAcumul$.subscribe(datos => (escala = datos));
    this.rubricaAcumul$.subscribe(datos => (rubrica = datos));
    this.criteriosAcumul$.subscribe(datos => (criterios = datos));

    let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));

    // Ultimos datos que agregar a la pauta.
    let extras = {
      usuarioModificacion: user.id
    };

    const pautaFinal: Pauta = {
      datosAdmin: admin,
      criterios: criterios,
      rubrica: rubrica,
      escala: escala,
      extras: extras
    };
    return of(pautaFinal);
  }
```

This is the function im calling in `y.service.ts`. It has some observables that are in the same service, it subscribes to them, gets some values, assign them to something else and then all those, put them inside a `pautaFinal` object, and that's what I return *as an observable*.

**What have i tried:**
  I've checked the chrome debugger and before the subscribe the array exists, after, it is empty.

This is the value of `escalaArr` inside the observable `this.escalaAcumul$` (from y.service)
[image: Before .subscribe() (escalaArr is the array that is lost)]

This is after the subscribe. Just one function call after the previous image.
[image: After .subscribe()]

This object has 4 more elements, and none of them change, just `escalaArr`.

I don't know what i'm doing wrong here. I've been stuck for a while and appreciate some help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clone the object handed in by the Observable before processing it. This way you break the 'by reference'-chain of JavaScript.

```
this.y
  .getSomething()
  .pipe(
    //make an observable to pass to child component 
    tap(data => (this.pautaFinal$ = of(data))),
    // This object is just for development purpose
    tap(data => (this.pautaFinal = data)),
    // This is to change the number[][] object into a number[][][]
    // I need it that way
    tap(
      data =>
        (this.escalaPorcionada = this.transformEscala(
          Object.assign({}, data.escala.escalaArr), // <-- clone here to avoid changing the original
          10
        ))
    )
  )
  .subscribe();
```

If this does not solve the problem check whether any other component has access to the setter of your Observable.

EDIT:

Option 2:

```
transformEscala(escala: number[][] = [], chunkSize: number): number[][][] {
    let results: number[][][] = [];
    const clone = Object.assign({}, escala);

while (clone.length) {
  results.push(clone.splice(0, chunkSize));
}
return results;
```

}

Comment: I tried `map(data => deepCopy(data) as Pauta`, before the first `tap()`, but same result.

Comment: Okay, I made an edit and added an option 2. Try to clone the object inside `transformEscala()`instead of inside the subscription.

Comment: Your vudu WORKED! Thanks man :clapping:!!!! Last thing, when you say "..instead of inside the subscription", you mean inside the `.subscribe()`? Because when I tried the `deepCopy` I did it before the `.subscribe()`??

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, I meant my example above where I put the Object.assign() inside the subscription()-block.

Comment: I tried to look for an explanation about the "clone" approach you proposed and couldn't find much. Could you recommend me somewhere to read about it. I need a better understanding.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no #1 page I could recommend on this topic. Sorry. -- The important point is the fact, that the `splice()`-operator changes the original array. In your case the array `escala`. So while you're splicing and pushing you  actually manipulate the array inside your service. That's why the array is empty afterwards. Here is how `splice()` works in general. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp . Using `Object.assign()` decouples the original object and your `splice()`-operation only affects your local copy. https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/object-assign-es6/

Comment: PS: Here is an interesting post concerning 'pass-by-reference', which is what happened in your example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference